# Yii2, как правильно обновлять данные залогиненного пользователя

Tags: php, yii2, авторизация

За документацией yii2 для того чтобы обновить его данные я должен сделать такую логику:

```
$model = self::findOne(['id' => $id]);
if($model->save()){
    return true;
}
        
return false;
```

НО я знаю что данные пользователя(залогиненного) находяться здесь `Yii::$app->user->identity;`

Тогда почему я не могу сделать так:

```
$model = Yii::$app->user->identity;
if($model->save()){
    return true;
}
        
return false;
```

Здесь также срабатывают все мои тригеры и не делается лишний запрос в БД. Почему такой метод плох?

Для чего мне (по документации) нужно делать лишний запрос в БД для обновления данных? (как в первом случае)

Comment: Есть ссылка на ту статью/документацию где про залогиненного пишут `$model = self::findOne(['id' => $id]);` ? Просто интересно не ошиблись ли вы интерпретации

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Возможно я не правильно понял документацию. Извините. Но думаю вопрос немного актуален из-за того что некоторые люди могут обмануть сами себя как это сделал я. Тоесть 2рой способ обновления юзер он хорош?

Comment: "*Возможно я не правильно понял документацию*" --- вот и прошу дать ссылку на то, где это прочитали, чтобы прояснить ситуацию............. "*2рой способ обновления юзер он хорош?*" --- ничего плохого в этом не вижу

Comment: @АлексейШиманский https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record

Comment: Там ни слова про обновление данных авторизованного пользователя. Там даже слова auth  не проскальзывает (во всяком случае я не нашёл даже через поиск)..... Там просто ищется какой-то пользователь по id. Это банально может быть админка и админ обновляет информацию о пользователе